# Why does right shift perform better than divide in JAVA?

Tags: java, jit

As we know, JIT will optimize division to have a better performance.
But when I try to calculate time that division and right shift cost:

```js
long j=0;
long a1=Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
for (long i = 0; i < 999999999l; i++) {
        j=i/2;//or j=i>>1;
}
long a2=Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
System.out.println(a2-a1);
```

Result:
j=i/2; 1070ms
j=i>>1; 702ms

I try it on different platforms but the results are quite same: right shift performs better.
Why doesn't JVM or JIT turn the /2 into >>1 to get better performance?

---

Thanks all. It seems that if dividend is a variable, compiler will not do the optimization. I change the dividend into a constant and the result shows /2 and >>1 perform equivalent.
PS. Thanks, System.currentTimeMillis() is better.

Comment: They’re not the same operation for negative numbers.

Comment: Some compilers are able to optimize out the loop entirely by removing it.

Comment: @minitech that should be an answer

Comment: by the way, use `System.currentTimeMillis()` or `System.nanoTime()` for timing

Comment: By the way, the bytecodes for both operations are not the same; integer divide is `idiv` and right shift is `ishr`

Comment: in decimal do you find it easier to shift 10000 by 2 digits or to divide 2 numbers?